# Sveltekit + NET 6 C# Api - After login, I cant call api which has authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, svelte

After login, I have jwt token and can login. But when I called other api in fetch function with jwt token, my api call got unauthorized. I cannot call api.

### NET 6 Api

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]))
    };
});
```

**LoginController.cs**

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                        new Claim(SessionConstant.UserName, user.UserName!),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole)
                }),
                Issuer = _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                Audience = _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

**UserController.cs**

```
[Authorize(Roles = RoleConstant.Developer)]
[HttpGet("GetUsers")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetUsers(User user)
```

### Sveltekit

**index.svelte**

```
// get = fetch with 'get' method.
let result = await get(`api/User/GetUsers?id=${id}`, accesstoken);
```

**utils.ts**

```
export async function get(endpoint, token) {
    let headers = {};
    
    if (token)
    {
        headers = {
            'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`
        };
    }

    return await fetch(`${baseApiUrl}/${endpoint}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers
    }).then(r => r.json())
        .then(x => x);
}
```

I have jwt token. Inside the jwt token, it shows my role is developer which matches with NET Api's [Authorize(Roles = RoleConstant.Developer)]. But I still cannot call GetUsers and it returns 'Unauthorization'. I tried 'Bearer ${token}' in 'Authorization' header too and it didn't work.

Anything I miss in code?

Comment: Can you check whether your token contains claims correctly or not by using https://jwt.io/ site?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I have checked it before already. {
  "UserName": "tester",
  "role": "DEVELOPER",
  "nbf": 1649577421,
  "exp": 1649578621,
  "iat": 1649577421,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5205",
  "aud": "http://localhost:3000"
}

Comment: Did you try to make request from Postman? If you tried, was it successfull?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just installed axios. It works fine. Weird, why fetch cannot work?

Comment: Can you try to setting header with this object````headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer  ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });````

Comment: Oh, it works now. so need to add content-type. Thanks. You can post answer. Will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this;

`headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer  ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });`